# How far is the CiviSocial integration under implementation?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-home, civicrm-buildkit

I am able to see some talks on CiviSocial.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Social+Media+Integration

How far is it implemented? How can I integrate my organization's Social Media initiatives with CiviCRM? If not CiviSocial is immediately available, what is the workaround?